# Y cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the output with the below Java program with an integer array using a for loop.

I get this error:

> y cannot be resolved to a variable

Here's the program:

```
public class For_loop {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {            

        int i [] = new int [5];

        i[0]=  100;
        i[1]=  200;
        i[2] = 300;
        i[3] = 400;
        i[4] = 500;

        for (int y=0; y<i.length; y++);         
        {                                   
           System.out.println (i[y]); // its giving me the error here                       
        }           
    }    
}
```

What do I need to do in order to get the output?

Comment: `for (int y=0; y<i.length; y++);` - remove `;`

Comment: remove ";" of your for loop

Comment: Thanks a lot Ori..it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon `;` at the end of your `for` loop:

```
for (int y=0; y<i.length; y++) {
        System.out.println (i[y]);
}
```

You've basically closed the loop (the statement) and therefore the block where `y` is declared was no longer available to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove semicolon ; that existed  at the  end of your for loop

```
for (int y=0; y<i.length; y++)
{
    System.out.println (i[y]);
}
```

And you must make sure the the semicolon ; after loop and after if statements will not make the the next statement or block to be executed with this loop or if, the next statement or block will be independent.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ahmad for your help :)